# Cannot add languages to Spellcheck in TeXWorks

Tags: latex, spell-checking

I use TeXWorks to edit my LaTeX files. Under spellcheck, the only options that I have are UK English and South African English, and I would like to install more languages.

In `/usr/share/myspell/dicts` many languaes are already present, but only the only aff files present are en_GB.aff en-GB.aff and en_ZA.aff

I cannot simply grab the aff files that I would like and put them there, because the
directory is protected as "root" editable only. The permission of dicts is ownede by
root and set to `rwxr-xr-x`.

I am quite sure that this is the correct directory.
`/usr/marc/`.`TeXworks/dictionaries` does not even exist.
`/usr/share/hunspell` also has Australian and US English in it and they do
not show up in my TexWorks dropdown menu.

How can I get past this root protection? Is there an install command that would allow me tograb these aff files somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem?

Have you installed the required hunspell dictionaries? TeXWorks uses hunspell to access the spelling dictionaries.